# Laravel query in blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How do you translate this query in `blade.php`

```
$developer_contractor_association = DeveloperContractorAssociation::whereHas('defect_types', function ($query) use($id) {
            $query->where('developer_contractor_associations.id', $id);
        })->orwhereHas('contractor', function ($query) use($id) {
            $query->where('developer_contractor_associations.id', $id);
        })->first();
    return view('dev-admin.contractors.associations.edit', ['developer_contractor_association' => $developer_contractor_association]);
```

I tried to use the method above but when it come to blade it doesn't work

```
@foreach($developer_contractor_association as $dca_details)
    <h2> {{ $dca_details->user->name }} </h2>
    <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>{{ $dca_details->contractor->address }}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>{{ $dca_details->user->email }}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></i>{{ $dca_details->contractor->contact_no }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Its says:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

**UPDATE :**

I made some mistake on query, I dont need the `foreach`, this fix my code. Thanks for everyone helps

```
<div id="contractor-details" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <h2> {{ $developer_contractor_association->contractor->user->name }} </h2>
    <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>{{ $developer_contractor_association->contractor->address }}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>{{ $developer_contractor_association->contractor->user->email }}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></i>{{ $developer_contractor_association->contractor->contact_no }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using `first()` that gives you an object. you can't iterate it. use `get()` if you need the iteration.

Comment: Hi @zahidhasanemon i change it to get but still get the same issue

Comment: show your `dd($developer_contractor_association)` result ?

Comment: when i dd in controller it works

Comment: show us your `DeveloperContractorAssociation` model. Do you have any relation named `user`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `get()` instead of `first()` , and after that use `dd($dca_details)` variable in `foreach()` to see if $dca_details has a user or not , if it had use  `dd($dca_details->user->name)`

and best way to handle this error is using:

> {{ $dca_details->user->name ?? '-' }}

Answer (score 1):

That is because one developer_contractor_association is not have user. You must be use

```
@foreach($developer_contractor_association as $dca_details)
    <h2> {{ $dca_details->user->name ?? 'User absent' }} </h2>
    <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>{{ $dca_details->contractor->address ?? ''}}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>{{ $dca_details->user->email ?? ''}}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>{{ $dca_details->contractor->contact_no ?? ''}}</p>
@endforeach
```

or you can use

```
@foreach($developer_contractor_association as $dca_details)
    @if(empty($dca_details->user) || empty($dca_details->contractor))
        @continue
    @endif
    <h2> {{ $dca_details->user->name }} </h2>
    <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>{{ $dca_details->contractor->address }}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>{{ $dca_details->user->email }}</p>
    <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>{{ $dca_details->contractor->contact_no }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Or in controller use

```
$developer_contractor_association = DeveloperContractorAssociation::whereHas('defect_types', function ($query) use($id) {
        $query->where('developer_contractor_associations.id', $id);
    })->orwhereHas('contractor', function ($query) use($id) {
        $query->where('developer_contractor_associations.id', $id);
    })->has('user')
   ->has('contractor')
   ->get();
return view('dev-admin.contractors.associations.edit', ['developer_contractor_association' => $developer_contractor_association]);
```